# How to dynamically access my models within a context?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I currently return the data of a model in the following way:

```
 _context.MyModel
```

where _context is of type DistributionContext, what I want is to dynamically access the models within the context, for example:

```
string modelName = "MyModel1";
_context.modelName;
```

Comment: What are you hoping to achieve?

Comment: Pass the Data to a function (s) to set different settings as Pagination

Comment: It is impossible due to that there is no generic `DbSet` for `DbContext`. Could you share us the reason for this purpose? we may try to check whether it is reasonable or any workaround.